# This script runs from Bash but not from Automator

Tags: macos, bash, automator

I am creating a service for finder, using automator. The service has only one item: "run shell script" and the script is this:

```
currentDirectory=$(pwd)


for f in "$@"; do

  DIRNAME="$(dirname "$f")"

  export width=$( mdls "$f"  | grep kMDItemPixelWidth | tail -n1 | cut -d= -f2 )
  export height=$( mdls "$f" | grep kMDItemPixelHeight | tail -n1 | cut -d= -f2 )

  oneWidth=$((width / 3)) 
  oneHeight=$((height / 3))

  twoWidth=$((umWidth * 2 ))
  twoHeight=$((umHeight * 2 ))

  IFS='@3x' read -ra NAMES <<< "$f"    #Convert string to array

  basename=${NAMES[0]}
  extension="${f##*.}"

  fullnameOne=${NAMES[0]}.$extension
  fullnameTwo=${NAMES[0]}@2x.$extension

  sips -z "$oneWidth" "$oneHeight" "$f" --out "$DIRNAME"/"$fullnameOne"
  sips -z "$twoWidth" "$twoHeight" "$f" --out "$DIRNAME"/"$fullnameTwo"

done
```

The idea is this:

1. I right click on a bunch of images which names contain `@3x`, like file@3x.png, ball@3x.jpg, etc.
2. I want the script to generate `@2x` and `@1x` versions of the files, renaming them file@2x.png, ball@2x.jpg, file.png and ball.jpg respectively.
3. The script has to respect the format. If the file is PNG, the output should be PNG and the same for JPG.

This script you see above runs from terminal, but not from automator. On automator the script generates just one file called `Users`.

What is wrong?

Comment: I miss the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29).

Comment: `IFS` doesn't work the way you think it does. Check the value of `$f` compared to the resulting value of `$basename`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is wrong?

Likely the arguments to the script. To test this hypothesis, add

```
 printf '<%s>\n' "$@" >$HOME/debug.out
```

after `currentDirectory=$(pwd)`.

If that doesn't help, also add `set -x` and redirect stderr to someplace you can find it.

Comment: Each argument is likely to be a full path, `/Users/someone/path/to/file@3x.png`.